# Area of a plane triangle as limit of a spherical triangle

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry

We know that the area of an spherical triangle (in a unit sphere) is given by
$A(\triangle) = \alpha + \beta + \gamma - \pi$, where $\alpha$, $\beta$, and
$\gamma$ are the interior angles of the spherical triangle.

I would like to see how plane (Euclidean) geometry works as a limit when the radius of the sphere goes to infinity. Clearly the curvature of the sphere $1/r$ becomes zero and a sphere turns into a plane. What happens to the area of the triangle?

If we say that the area of the triangle is 
\begin{equation}
  A(\triangle) = r^2 [(\alpha + \beta + \gamma) - \pi]
\end{equation}
clearly $\alpha + \beta + \gamma - \pi$ go to zero, but not
at the rate that $r^2$ goes to infinity. It seems that this limit
is infinity.

There seems to me that we can not find something like $b h/2$ (base times height over two) from spherical geometry. Right?

Of course objects become amplified in area by $r^2$ or length by $r$
so we would need to have something to pull them back.

Thanks.

---

**Update:**
One way to pull back is to think that the actual arc lengths of the
stretched triangle segments are $a=r \alpha$, $b=r \beta$, and
$c= r \gamma$, so we can pull one $r$ inside the formula above and have

\begin{equation}
  A(\triangle) = r [(a+b+c) - \pi r]
\end{equation}

where now $a,b$, and $c$ are the actual lengths of the sides. 
Pulling $r$ inside again shows me the area of a circle and...
it seems that we better point toward

[Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula)

and forget about base x height/2. Heron's formula is fine to me.

Comment: Wow! you are fast! I just sent this. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo Normal Human is (mostly) a bot, the comment will be deleted automatically in a few minutes.

Comment: The arc lengths on the surface of the sphere are not $r \alpha$, $r \beta$, and $r \gamma$.  This would be the case if all three angles were the angles subtended _by the arcs_, but  $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are the angles _between the arcs_ in the formula you gave.  See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalTriangle.html), for example.

Comment: @Michael Selfert : The angle $\alpha$ is by definition the dihedral angle which is formed by the two lunes (or better, the two planes) which form the vertex where $\alpha$ is assigned. So even though in the figures shown in books and websites $\alpha$ looks like an angle in the surface, it goes the same all the way to the center of the sphere.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert : I believe you are right. The letters $a$, $b$, and $c$ which measure the arc length of each side of the spherical triangle are also the angles of the intersection with the plane having those segments and the sphere, if the sphere is unitary. If the sphere grows as $r$ in the radial direction, then those angles shrink if we want to preserve the arc lengths of $a$, $b$, and $c$. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found a connection here. We need to use 
[Cagnoli's Theorem](https://books.google.com/books?id=KqlXAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA48&lpg=RA1-PA48&dq=Cagnoli%27s%20theorem&source=bl&ots=ype2BN3L4B&sig=_G-tvo_d4XdO3IlICWXHwjIT0t0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD0Q6AEwCGoVChMItpaMq7mayQIVzHQ-Ch1RSgMb#v=onepage&q=Cagnoli%27s%20theorem&f=false)

That is, given excess $E=\alpha+\beta+\gamma-\pi= A(\triangle)$ 
Cagnoli's Theorem establishes that:

\begin{equation}
\sin \frac{E}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{ \sin s \sin (s-a) \sin (s-b) \sin(s-c)}}{
{2 \cos \frac{a}{2} \cos \frac{b}{2} \cos \frac{c}{2}}}
\end{equation}

Then as we write the trigonometrical functions as Taylor series:

\begin{eqnarray*}
   \sin x &=& x - \frac{x^3}{3} + H.O.T. \\
    \cos x &=& 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + H. O. T.
\end{eqnarray*}

When $r \to \infty$ we get an asymptotic solution by retaining only
the leading order terms here. That is

\begin{equation}
\lim_{r \to \infty} \sin \frac{E}{2} =  \lim_{r \to \infty} \frac{E}{2}.
\end{equation}
(note that the radius $r$ is implicit on these equations, in addition
when $r \to \infty$, $E \to 0$ since the excess will be nothing once you get from a sphere to a plane.).
Similarly for the right hand side term, as $r \to \infty$ we find

\begin{equation}
\lim_{r \to \infty}
\frac{\sqrt{ \sin s \sin (s-a) \sin (s-b) \sin(s-c)}}{
{2 \cos \frac{a}{2} \cos \frac{b}{2} \cos \frac{c}{2}}} =
 \lim_{r \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}}{2}
\end{equation}
Please observe that for very large $r$ the interior angles
$a$, $b$, and $c$ become really small and so their semi-perimeter $s$.
That is, if $r=1$, then $a$, $b$, and $c$ are simultaneously lengths of
the triangle sides (arc segments) and central angles in the sphere.
If we want to increase $r \gg 1$, then, in order to preserve the
size of the segments, we need to shrink the angles by a factor of
$1/r$, so that the central angles $a$, $b$, and $c$ shrink to zero,
but the length of the segments $a$, $b$, and $c$ remain constant. Hence
there is a duality on the meaning of the symbols $a$, $b$, and $c$. 
As arguments of the sine and cosine functions, they are angles in radians, but as lengths they are the fixed lengths for $r=1$ and they should be 
preserved as the sphere explodes. What I call "pull back" in my question is this shrinking of $a$, $b$ , and $c$ as central angles of the sphere to keep the arc lengths of $a$, $b$, and $c$ constant.

From the previous two equations we find that
in the limit as $r \to \infty$:

\begin{equation}
E = \sqrt{s (s-a) (s-b) (s-c)}.
\end{equation}

which is [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula). The conversion from here to base x altitude/2 should be a common problem solved elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

We apply the Spherical Law of Cosines for Angles and render the planar area from the limiting form of this law.

Begin by rendering the arc lengths on a sphere of radius $R$* as $a,b,c$ and the respective opposite angles as $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. The planar limit is to be obtained as $R\to\infty$ with $\alpha,\beta,c$ fixed.

(* -- We do not assume a unit radius, so  "extra" factors of $R$ will appear in formulas below.)

From the spherical trigonometry law described above, we then have

$\cos\gamma=-\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\sin\beta\cos(c/R)$

We render $\cos(c/R)$ as $1-[1-\cos(c/R)]$ and apply the formula for the cosine of a sum to obtain

$\cos\gamma+\cos(\alpha+\beta)=-\sin\alpha\sin\beta[1-\cos(c/R)]$

Next comes the sum-product relation for cosines:

$2\cos\left(\dfrac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}2\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{\alpha+\beta-\gamma}2\right)=-\sin\alpha\sin\beta[1-\cos(c/R)]$

$2\sin\left(\dfrac{\Delta}{2R^2}\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{\alpha+\beta-\gamma}2\right)=\sin\alpha\sin\beta[1-\cos(c/R)]$ (***)

where $\Delta$ is the area of the triangle and $\Delta/R^2=\alpha+\beta+\gamma-\pi$ is the spherical excess in radians.

We now apply our approximations for the planar limit. First:

$\sin\left(\dfrac{\Delta}{2R^2}\right)\sim\dfrac{\Delta}{2R^2}$

$\cos\left(\dfrac{\alpha+\beta-\gamma}2\right)\sim\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi-2\gamma}2\right)=\sin\gamma$

$1-\cos(c/R)=\dfrac{1-\cos^2(c/R)}{1+\cos(c/R)}\sim\dfrac{\sin^2(c/R)}2$

So then (***) becomes

$\left(\dfrac{\Delta}{R^2}\right)\sim\left(\dfrac{\sin\alpha\sin\beta}{\sin\gamma}\right)\dfrac{\sin^2(c/R)}2$

We now plug in the Law of Sines to render

$\dfrac{\sin^2(c/R)}{\sin^2\gamma}=\left(\dfrac{\sin(a/R)}{\sin\alpha}\right)\left(\dfrac{\sin(b/R)}{\sin\beta}\right)$

and obtain

$\Delta\sim\frac12R^2\sin(a/R)\sin(b/R)\sin\gamma\sim\frac12ab\sin\gamma,$

which matches the planar formula.